# Compile SASS in multiple directories of identical structure using gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have following structure of SCSS files

```
/modules/core/scss/core.scss
/modules/blog/scss/blog.scss
```

I have now my gulp file like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./modules/*/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./modules'));
})
```

of course it produces same directory.

Is there a way to compile those using gulp using single pipe? I need result like so (change scss to css):

```
/modules/core/css/core.scss
/modules/blog/css/blog.scss
```

Modules is dynamically added so I can not add one pipe for each module.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp has a [recipe in its documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md) for exactly this scenario.

Copy/paste just in case:

---

## Generating a file per folder

If you have a set of folders, and wish to perform a set of tasks on each, for instance...

```
/scripts
/scripts/jquery/*.js
/scripts/angularjs/*.js
```

...and want to end up with...

```
/scripts
/scripts/jquery.min.js
/scripts/angularjs.min.js
```

...you'll need to do something like the following...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var merge = require('merge-stream');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var scriptsPath = 'src/scripts';

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
   var folders = getFolders(scriptsPath);

   var tasks = folders.map(function(folder) {
      // concat into foldername.js
      // write to output
      // minify
      // rename to folder.min.js
      // write to output again
      return gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, folder, '/**/*.js'))
        .pipe(concat(folder + '.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename(folder + '.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath));
   });

   // process all remaining files in scriptsPath root into main.js and main.min.js files
   var root = gulp.src(path.join(scriptsPath, '/*.js'))
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(scriptsPath));

   return merge(tasks, root);
});
```

A few notes:

- `folders.map` - executes the function once per folder, and returns the async stream
- `merge` - combines the streams and ends only when all streams emitted end